# Google sheets QUERY with reference to another cell with number

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I want to query a column based on the value of a cell I am referencing in the formula.

[partial screenshot of sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX4qP.png)

I'd expect the formula in F3 to retrieve all values of column D below the value defined in F6.
Instead I get a #VALUE! error.

Is anyone able to help me with this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any value less than `13588` in column D? It seems query didn't find any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies than in your locale you use the comma as a separator for decimals, but QUERY uses the dot to do that. So when you pass that cell as an argument it returns an error.

Maybe there's a more elegant way (I've tried TEXT(F6;"0.0") but has the same issue), you can replace your cell reference with a string created with the rounded part before the comma, a dot, and the remaining part:

```
ROUND(F6;0)&"."&ROUND(MOD(F6;1)*100000)
```

PS: replace 100000 with as 0s as decimals you may need

Then, the whole Query would look:

```
=QUERY(D:D;"SELECT D WHERE D > "&ROUND(F6;0)&"."&ROUND(MOD(F6;1)*100000))
```

[image]

Comment: That is fascinating.. Would have never expected the problem to come from the decimals.
Thank you a lot.
2 questions if you are so kind:
1. How did you figure this out?
2. Why was I downvoted?

Comment: I'm glad it was useful! I live in a hispanic country with the same locale as yours, but have to share files with others. This issue in particular hadn't arised before, but knowing that QUERY work with a string, I had the hypothesis that it wouldn't be able to adapt the decimal separator; so I tested it and could reproduce it, tried manualy inputing the number with the dot inside the string and worked, so that led me to this "workaround". About your downvote, it could possibly be because you were supposed to reproduce the problem inside the question and share what you've tried

Comment: PS: you also have many options to work with FILTER, that wouldn't have some of the limitations that QUERY has. I suggest you investigate it. For example, your case could be translated as: `=FILTER(D:D;D:D>F6)`

Comment: I see.. that is very helpful. Coming from python, the problem was just completely unexpected. So, thanks again! Will check out filter for sure, too!
And regarding the downvote: I think that makes sense. Will make sure to provide more information next time.